# How to specify scalacOptions individually for files

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to specify for a file compiler options that differs from entire projects. To be more concrete, there is some debugging that I need to enable to figure out why macros fails in that particular file. If I change the options globally, then the entire project would be recompiled (and produce debug), which I want to avoid.

How am I supposed to do that with sbt?

Comment: Why not use `scalac print` and pass that specific file?

Comment: I should also pass all dependencies.

Comment: Can you specify more what kind of error you see?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to give special compilation parameters that applies only to some files of a compilation unit.

Macros are difficult to debug. Now the possible solutions are:

- [Debug the code](https://vimeo.com/75771830)
- `println` in the macro's code, `sbt clean compile` and you should see your prints in the console (It also works in Idea).

Good luck

Comment: @som-snytt I removed the "this is why they need to be avoided as much as possible" even tho it's pretty clear that macros are an experimental feature that are supposed to be avoided and will even go away to be replaced by scala.meta.

Answer (score 3):

Using the SBT's incremental compilation feature, you can have the following workaround:

1. Enable this compiler option for the whole project,
2. Compile the whole project (you'll get a lot of output which you can ignore for now)
3. Execute `touch <file with macro>.scala` from console, or do some other modification in that file only.
4. Compile again.

Now only single file of interest (and possibly files that depend on it) will be recompiled, and there'll be much less debug output.

The above implies your code compiles successfully. If it doesn't you need to bring it to state when it does compile successfully first (e.g. by removing some code that fails the compilation in the file you're interested in), and then go to step 3 from above.